# What do the symbols $\mu$ and $\nu$ mean in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

I'm not an expert on general relativity, and below the tensors in the Einstein Field Equations, there are two confusing symbols: $\mu$ and $\nu$ below them. What do they mean? Any equations are appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you mean (though I can guess that you mean the tensor indices – these are dummy indices to describe the structure of the tensor equations – see e.g. <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation>). It is customary to use Greek indices for relativistic 4-tensors (and latin indices when restricting them to the three space dimensions). The $\upsilon$ is  usually actually a $\nu$.

Comment: I think the comment above answers your question. If not, please clarify your question. If however, it is indeed what you were asking about, please consider looking up basic literature before asking a question. Information about the index notation is literally linked on the Wikipedia page on General Relativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't know a lot about GR so this is somewhat simplified.

In general relativity we frequently write second rank tensors as matrices. For example the Schwarzschild metric is usually written as the matrix:

$$g=\left(\begin{matrix}
-c^2(1-\frac{r_s}{r}) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{1-\frac{r_s}{r}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{matrix}\right)$$

An element in a matrix is identified by its row and column number. These can be written as subscripts or superscripts depending on the matrix (the details are a little complicated and certainly beyond the scope of this answer). In the case of the metric tensor we would write $g_{\mu\nu}$ where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the row and column number in the matrix.

It's traditional to use Greek letters as sub/superscripts when dealing with tensors, and this is why you so often see such sub/superscripts in equations related to GR.